# Нечто(,) вроде

Tags: пунктуация

В таких оборотах после слова "нечто" нужна запятая или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша логика довольно понятна. Вы сомневаетесь, являются ли обороты с "вроде" обособленными определениями. Нет, не являются. Так что нет, в вашем примере не надо ставить никаких знаков препинания.

> То же, что «наподобие, типа». Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «вроде», обычно не обособляются.
>
> *В деле княгини Друбецкой он почувствовал, однако, после ее нового призыва, что-то вроде укора совести.* Л. Толстой, Война и мир.
> *В середине трюма оставлен проход вроде коридора…* В. Короленко, Соколинец.
> ([Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_110))